# recursion function says undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to figure out why this recursion function keeps saying undefined.

```
function countDown(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return;
    }
    countDown(num - 1);
}

console.log(countDown(10));
```

Comment: You never `return` any *value* from your function.

Comment: What is it that you *expect* it to return? Zero?

Answer (score 1):

A "naked" `return` statement is effectively the same as

```
return undefined;
```

In the other case, your function has no `return` at all, so that's also like

```
return undefined;
```

Thus in all cases your function returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return a value; therefore it returns `undefined`.

```js
function foo() {
  return;
}

console.log(foo());

function bar() {}

console.log(bar());
```

Answer (score 1):

If `num` is `0` then you hit a `return` statement with nothing after it, so the function returns `undefined`.

If `num` is any other value, then you don't hit a `return` statement at all, so the function still returns `undefined`.

In this particular example, the only time you look at the return value is when you `num` is `10`. That's "any other value".

Answer (score 1):

It returns `undefined` because you are not returning anything. To be able to see the result, e.g. log the `num` value with every cycle or return `stop` string at the end.

```js
function countDown(num) {
  console.log(num);
  if (num === 0) {
    return 'stop';
  }
  return countDown(num - 1);
}

console.log(countDown(4));
```